# Selecting TOP 4 records from multiple SQL Server tables. Using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have about 4 different tables with the exact same column names.  What I would like to do is select the top 4 records out of all of these tables combined ordered by date (as date is one of the columns that they all share).

I keep getting erroneous statements, whether it be a syntax issue or ambiguous record etc.

Essentially my statement is similar to:

```
SELECT TOP 4 date, link, anchor, thumb FROM archive1, archive2, archive3, archive4 ORDER BY date DESC
```

To state the obvious, I'm new to all this stuff.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to produce [union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of all tables and then order them to get last four:

```
SELECT TOP 4 date, link, anchor, thumb 
FROM
(
  SELECT date, link, anchor, thumb 
    FROM archive1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date, link, anchor, thumb 
    FROM archive2
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date, link, anchor, thumb 
    FROM archive3
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date, link, anchor, thumb 
   FROM archive4 
) archive
ORDER BY date DESC
```

As you only take four records you might add TOP 4 clause to each query along with ORDER BY date DESC to speed things up.

Comment: Assuming the first table has at least 4 records, isn't this going to ensure that the "top 4" always come from the first table?  No point in querying the other tables then...

Comment: Yes -- you're putting the "top 4" in order -- I see that.  But wouldn't you want to apply the ordering to the unionized set *before* you took the top 4?  (to ensure that all of the tables came into play, not just the first one)

Comment: This is correct. The top and order-by will work together. The top will be applied after the ordering.

Comment: Beautiful this worked great!  Thanks. Now I have a follow up, perhaps I should make a different question for it. I would like to load each of those 4 columns for each of the 4 top rows into labels.  I tried declaring a datareader and execute reader but dr only produces 4 items as item dr.item(4) was outside of the array.  Is each item a combination of all four columns?

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, a new question would be great to keep things organized :-)